# How to control exported symbols when writing a static library in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, static-libraries

I want to build a static library, which has some functions/variables/etc. exported, and others internally used by the library. Everything exported is C-style.

How to achieve this?

What I have tried is the following:

---

MyLib.h

```
int Test(int a, int b);
```

MyLib.cpp

```
#include "MyLib.h"
int Private(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
int Test(int a, int b)
{
    return Private(a, b);
}
```

And this is how I use the library:

Main.cpp

```
#include "MyLib.h"
int main()
{
    int x = Test(4, 6);
    ...
}
```

---

All these seem to work well.

However, I find that the function `Private` is also exported.

Thus the following code will also compile and link:

Main.cpp

```
#include "MyLib.h"
int Private(int a, int b);
int main()
{
    int x = Private(4, 6);
    ...
}
```

Therefore, I guess that I have polluted the global namespace, and now I cannot define a function called `Private` in `Main.cpp`, because the linker will complain that this symbol already exists.

---

So how do I control which functions/variables/symbols are visible to the codes that use the library?

After doing some search, I find that declaring the `Private` function in `MyLib.cpp` as `static` seems to solve the problem. However, I'm not sure if this is the best way. To me, it would make more sense to "mark" those that I want to export, rather than to "mark" those that I want to hide, since I only want to export a small portion of all the symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version:

The OS doesn't recognize static libs as being anything it understands.  It only deals with exe's, dll's, and data files.  You build a static lib to merge it into 1 or more exe's and|or dll's, basically to save recompiling it for each.

As such, the expectation is that you want to be able to access all the code|data in the static lib when building the exe or dll you've linked it to.

In contrast, an exe|dll can have security applied by the OS, and is considered a 'final product', so by default everything is private unless explicitly marked as exported.

So, either:

- use a static lib and put all 'private stuff' in a .cpp e.g. marked as static like you've discovered, or in an anonymous namespace, or ...
- use a dll and mark all 'public stuff' as exported.

Answer (score -1):

```
static int Private(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```